# attach failed with error： java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Tags: java, instruments, javaagents

while I try to attach a process with code like:

```
vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
vm.loadAgent(attachJarPath, properties);
```

I got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:248)
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.execute(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:199)
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:58)
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:79)
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:103)
```

what can i do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found the reason：
the paratemers of "properties" transfer to aim JVM cannot be too long in:
vm.loadAgent(attachJarPath, properties);
because of the limit of attach Ti support;

you can use a file to transfer your data